# Book on logic similar in tone/difficulty to halmos' naive set theory

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

Is there anything like this out there? The book is excellent for light reading, and I'm looking for a way to brush up basic logic (propositional / fol) in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I found that Hodges’ Logic (not Chiswell & Hodges though) is exactly what I was looking for.